# Car Radiator Coolant Leak

Tags: coolant, radiator

I have a coolant leak coming from somewhere in this region (circled in red):

[image]

It's a very small leak as I just need to top it up by about ~100ml monthly? I don't really want to pay and replace it unless it gets worse (as car has other issues that may cause failure before this). I've been looking for a temporary/permanent fix and considering using repair putty?

[image]

It should adhere well and the putty is resistant to temperatures of +150 Celsius, I believe coolant/radiator would be slightly below that?

Any other fix/advise possible for such a scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think the tube of putty would probably do the job for you, but who knows.

You could always try the old school method of putting some ground pepper (yes, the shaker which is next to the salt kind of pepper) in the coolant. The pepper catches at the leak and plugs it. Very cost effective way to stop a very small leak, especially in a vehicle which you feel is on its last leg anyways.